# C++ program that calculates all possibilities of a sum with given numbers (duplicates allowed)

Tags: c++, recursion, sum, combinations

I need to write a program in C++ that takes a set amount of numbers (specifically 1 and 2) and then calculates how many combinations these numbers can forum a total sum.

For example if the total sum we wanted was '3'. Then the program would return that there are 3 possible combinations (1+1+1, 1+2, 2+1). What I mostly am stuck on is how to calculate being able to use a number in the list multiple times.

If possible I would also like to know if their is a non recursive way of solving this problem. Pseudo code would be fine as well. I simply would just like a idea of the structure of a program that can satisfy this.

My initial plan went as follows:

```
int SumCombinations(int numberOfcombos)
{

    if (numberOfcombos == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int results = 1; //will always be at least one arrangement 

    if (numberOfcombos % 2 == 0)
    {
        results++; //can be made up of only '2' values
    }

    int temp = 0;
    while (temp < numberOfcombos)
    {
        temp += 1;
        temp += 2;
    }
    if (temp == numberOfcombos)
    {
        results++;
    }
    temp = 0;
    while (temp < numberOfcombos)
    {
        temp += 2;
        temp += 1;
    }
    if (temp == numberOfcombos)
    {
        results++;
    }


        return results;
}
```

Since we can use duplicate '1' values their will always be at least 1 possible result, and if the total sum is even then we know all '2' values is also viable. After this however is when I get lost on how to find all other combinations.

Comment: Why e.g. `temp += 1; temp += 2;` instead of the single `temp += 3;`? And IMO a `for` loop might have been better, or at least clearer.

Comment: This is a famous problem. The answer is supposed to be "Aga, it's just *<this famous number sequence>* (insert sequence here)". Programming the sequence non-recursively is left as an exercise for the reader. By the way `if (numberOfcombos == 0) {return 0;}` is wrong, it is supposed to be 1 (there is one way to represent 0 as a sum of a set of non-negative integers, namely the empty set).

Comment: Didn't Ramanujan have something to do with this problem?

Comment: Hm... Shouldn't we be able to create a closed formula? Forget about the all one's, we get that implicitly; apart from the sum being one we *always* have the twos only solution – with odd numbers having an additional `+ 1`. All of these twos can be represented by either `2` directly or `(1 + 1)`, so the question is equivalent to how many strings of length of `sum & ~1` containing an arbitrary sequence of `a`s and `b`s do exist.

Comment: For odd numbers we might yet need to consider the possible location of the `+ 1` – which might produce duplicates, though (e.g. `(1 + 1) + 1 + 2` vs. `1 + (1 + 1) + 2`) so we cannot simply multiply by `sum & ~1`, but need to divide by number of duplicates produced that way – where again a closed formula should exist for.

Comment: @john you're off by a few hundred years.

Comment: @Aconcagua why not calculate the answer for the first few inputs? Then who knows, a closed formula might become apparent.

Comment: @n.m. ... and ideally prove via induction – might do at some later time ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua one needs to know *what* to prove, the proof is then trivial.

Comment: @n.m. Oh, my, we get the [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence) ;)

Comment: And it's even not that heavy do deduce, we can prepend a 1 to all combinations received by `sum - 1` and a 2 to all combinations received by (sum - 2) – with that, the FS is explained/proved, though lacking yet that we won't miss any possible combination (no duplicates is simple, too, as all combinations from one range start with 1, the other ones with 2).

Answer (score 1):

Well, to get a clue about what's going on we might try to implement a naive counting approach.

Obviously to create numbers from ones and twos we can start with some initial sequences of ones and twos, e.g. for number 7:

```
1111111
11111 2
111  22
1   222
```

or in the general case:

```
(sum - 0) x 1     0 x 2
(sum - 2)         1 x 2
...
(sum - n) x 1     n x 2  with n == sum/2 (integer division)
```

For each of above sequences we need to count all permutations of (we might indeed create these sequences and use `std::next_permutation` for a primitive algorithm) to get all possible combinations.

Now lets examine the combinations a bit closer, especially if there's a way to deduce the combinations for new numbers from their predecessors. Obviously a number `n` can be calculated as `1 + (n - 1)` or `2 + (n - 2)`. So if we have the combinations available for `n - 1` and `n - 2` we simply can prepend (or alternatively append) a `1` to all combinations of `n - 1` and a `2` to all combinations of `n - 2`. We cannot get any duplicates this way (assuming there are no duplicates in the predecessors): Combinations from different predecessors calculate a different number so there naturally cannot be duplicates within these; we produce two sets of new combinations where all members of one set have an initial `1`, all members of the other one an initial `2`, so again no duplicates possible.

Actually lacking is the prove that we do not miss any possible combination this way (I might add later; you do not seem to rely on anyway).

In any case we can conclude:

The number of new combinations for a given `sum` is the sum of the numbers of combinations of its two predecessors, i.e. `combinations(sum) = combinations(sum - 1) + combinations(sum - 2)` – and with starting values for 0 (we can include it, there's just one combination possible not containing any summands at all...) and 1 (again just one combination possible) we get the famous [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence). So we can apply the well-known closed formula to calculate the sequence (careful if calculating with floating point, i.e. `double` – you need to consider rounding errors!) or any of the existing integral algorithms (do not implement naively by recursion, you'll calculate the same sums multiple times!), e.g. like:

```
size_t fibonacci(size_t n)
{
    if(n <= 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    size_t f0 = 1;
    size_t f1 = 1;

    while(--n)
    {
        std::swap(f0, f1);
        f1 += f0;
    }
    return f1;
}
```

Or with lookup table (as is not thread-safe):

```
size_t fibonacci(size_t n)
{
    static std::vector<size_t> values({1, 1});
    if(n >= values.size())
    {
        values.reserve(n + 1);
        while(values.size() <= n)
        {
            values.push_back(values.back() + *(values.end() - 2));
        }
    }
    return values[n];
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation of why we are looking for the Fibonacci numbers. The SO reputation system is ill-suited for this kind of questions/answers which takes some analysis. Once you get the answer written, the question is far down the list and only few people sees it. Also, the answer may be too complicated for most people to understand. Anyway, here is an upvote from me :-).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some new problem, but you hit the very well known problem called "coin change". Since it is very old, there are tons of solutions available.

The transformation of your given problem that needs to be done is, that your sum is the "change" and your coins are 1 and 2.

You can find a good explanation of the algorithm [here](https://algorithmist.com/wiki/Coin_change) or also on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem). Solutions in all languages can be found at [rosetta code](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Count_the_coins).

The idea is that you take the sum and then subtract all kinds of existing elements (coins) from this sum. If you hit 0, then you found a solution. If it goes below 0, then, oviously, this is not a solution.

This approach can be very simply implemented using a trivial recursive algorithm. But you will find on youtub many solutions that show none-recursive, DP (dynamic programming) based codes.

Becuase of its simplicity, I will show the recursive approach here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

long countRrecursive(const int sum, const std::vector<long>& input, long count, std::vector<long>::const_iterator current) {
    if (sum == 0) return 1;     // Solution found. Add 1 to the count
    if (sum < 0)  return 0;     // No solution found. This path will not be counted

    for (auto iter = current; iter != input.end(); ++iter)  // Try all possible paths
        count += countRrecursive(sum - *iter, input, 0, iter);
    return count;
}
int main() {
    int sum =4;                                 // The sum that we are looking for
    std::vector<long> elements = { 1,2 };       // And the elements that should build the sum

    std::sort(elements.begin(), elements.end(), std::greater<long>());
    std::cout << "Count: " << countRrecursive(sum, elements, 0, elements.begin()) << '\n';
}
```